# How to indent the first line only in tcolorbox

Tags: tcolorbox

How to indent only the first line in `tcolorbox`?

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[listings,many]{tcolorbox}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\tcbuselibrary{listingsutf8,breakable,skins}
\tcbset{listing engine=listings}
\tcbset{mystyle/.style={
  breakable,
  enhanced,
  rightrule=0pt,
  toprule=0pt,
  outer arc=0pt,
  before upper={\parindent17pt},
parbox = true,
  arc=0pt,
  colback=white,
  attach boxed title to top left,
  fonttitle=\sffamily
  }
}
\newtcolorbox[auto counter]{mybox}[1][]{
  mystyle,colframe=black,boxed title style={
    colback=black,
    outer arc=0pt,
    arc=0pt,
    top=0pt,
    bottom=0pt,
left=1pt,
right=1pt
    },
left=0pt,right=0pt,top=-18pt,bottom=0pt, 
  title=\thetcbcounter,
  overlay unbroken and first={
      \path
        let
        \p1=(title.north west),
        \p2=(frame.north west)
        in
        node[anchor=west,font=\sffamily,text width=\x2-\x1]
        at (title.west) {#1};
  }
}
\begin{document}


\begin{mybox}
\lipsum[1-8]
\end{mybox}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Without the indent the text will be pretty unreadable. Do you want a blank line between parargraphs like the `parskip` package does?

Comment: Do not skip between paragraphs. I want only the first line to be indented. Because the text is not long and it needs to be without indentation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've set the `\parindent` to be `17pt`, but you really only want this to make room for the numbered title box. So you really need `\parindent=0pt` and then a manual indent in the first paragraph.

You can achieve this by using:

```
before upper={\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}\hspace*{17pt}}
```

Here's a full example:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[listings,many]{tcolorbox}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\tcbuselibrary{listingsutf8,breakable,skins}
\tcbset{listing engine=listings}
\tcbset{mystyle/.style={
  breakable,
  enhanced,
  rightrule=0pt,
  toprule=0pt,
  outer arc=0pt,
  before upper={\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}\hspace*{17pt}},
parbox = true,
  arc=0pt,
  colback=white,
  attach boxed title to top left,
  fonttitle=\sffamily
  }
}
\newtcolorbox[auto counter]{mybox}[1][]{
  mystyle,colframe=black,boxed title style={
    colback=black,
    outer arc=0pt,
    arc=0pt,
    top=0pt,
    bottom=0pt,
left=1pt,
right=1pt
    },
left=0pt,right=0pt,top=-18pt,bottom=0pt, 
  title=\thetcbcounter,
  overlay unbroken and first={
      \path
        let
        \p1=(title.north west),
        \p2=(frame.north west)
        in
        node[anchor=west,font=\sffamily,text width=\x2-\x1]
        at (title.west) {#1};
  }
}
\begin{document}


\begin{mybox}
\lipsum[1-2]
\end{mybox}

\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Comment: Thanks. If I want to change the box to an oval and it goes a little to the left, is it possible?

Comment: @H.Gorbanzad That should probably be a separate question. But which box do you mean? The one with the number? You can change it to a circle using `circular arc` but I don't know of a way offhand to make it an oval. So I would ask a new question about that.

Comment: I'd prefer `\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}\hspace*{17pt}`

Comment: @egreg Fair enough. :) I've updated the code. Thanks.

Comment: @egreg, Thanks.

Comment: @Alan Munn, Thanks. Did you ask a new question about it?

Comment: @H.Gorbanzad No, it's not my problem, it's your problem, so you should ask the question.